# rebuild prototype Ajax POST into "plain" js

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

What i need is to rebuild prototype.js Ajax request via javascript. (no jQuery / no fetch). IE sopport is required (for some reasons...)

```
new Ajax.Request(
urlVar,
{
  method: 'post',
  parameters: {elid: document.getElementById('element').selectedIndex},
  onCreate: function(){
    //do somethings
  },
  onComplete: fucnction (event){
    currentValues = eval('(' + event.responseText + ')');
    console.log(currentValues); // will give me an array with 3 objects
  }
});
```

What i have tried is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", urlVar, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
         currentValues = eval('(' + event.responseText + ')');
         console.log(currentValues); // i see an error that "currentValues" is undefined
         //i can get 1 object if i will do eval('(' + THIS.responseText + ')');
         // but it still bugs me a lot..

         //other actions here
      }
      else if (xhr.status == 400) {
         console.log('ERROR')
      }
      else {
         console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
      }
   }
}
xhr.send(document.getElementById('element').selectedIndex);
```

Maybe someone know which construction will work in this case. 
Is there some way in order to do onCreate / onComplete via js?

Comment: Never ever `eval` that responsetext. Use `JSON.parse`. Use a polyfill for those really old browsers that don't have it.

Comment: Did you take a look at the source code of `Ajax.Request`? It's not that complicated.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: im doing somethings wrong because in 1 example (prototype) -> console log would show me an array with 3 objects.

but in case of javascript version -> only 1

Comment: You're probably sending the parameter wrong. Take a look at the network panel in the developer tools to figure out how the requests differ. My guess would be that you're looking for `xhr.send("elid="+encodeURIComponent(…selectedIndex))`.

Comment: You are an absolute legend my man. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.responseText`, `xhr.responseText` (the same way that you already access `.status` and `.readyState`) or `event.target.responseText`. The `event` does not have a `responseText` itself.